# Remove partial duplicates consecutive lines but keep first and last

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have log files with a time stamp and six values in each line
i want to reduce the amount of data, by removing consecutive lines with the same values (ignoring time stamps) and keeping the first and last line of each duplicate set. Preferably using a bash script. It should be a magic `sed` or `awk` command combination.

Even if i have to parse the file multiple times, reading 3 lines at a time and removing the middle one, is a good solution.

original file:

```
1447790360      99999   99999   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790362      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790365      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790368      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790371      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790374      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790377      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790380      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790383      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790386      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790388      20.25   20.25   99999   99999   99999   99999
1447790389      99999   99999   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790391      20.00   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790394      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790397      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790400      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
```

desired result:

```
1447790360      99999   99999   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790362      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790386      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790388      20.25   20.25   99999   99999   99999   99999
1447790389      99999   99999   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790391      20.00   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790394      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790400      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

uniq is (sort of) the perfect tool for this, by default in uniq you can keep/show the first but not last line in set.

uniq has a -f flag which allows you to skip the first few fields.

From man uniq:

```
   -f, --skip-fields=N
          avoid comparing the first N fields

   -s, --skip-chars=N
          avoid comparing the first N characters

   A field is a run of blanks (usually spaces and/or TABs), then non-blank characters.  Fields are skipped before chars.
```

Example with uniq -c to show count see what uniq is doing:

```
-bash-4.2$ uniq -c -f 1 original_file
  1 1447790360      99999   99999   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
  9 1447790362      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
  1 1447790388      20.25   20.25   99999   99999   99999   99999
  1 1447790389      99999   99999   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
  1 1447790391      20.00   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
  3 1447790394      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
```

Not bad. 
Pretty close to what is wanted.
And easy to do.
But missing the last matching line in group . . . .

The grouping options in uniq are also interesting for this question . . .

```
   --group[=METHOD]
          show all items, separating groups with an empty line METHOD={separate(default),prepend,append,both}

   -D, --all-repeated[=METHOD]
          print all duplicate lines groups can be delimited with an empty line METHOD={none(default),prepend,separate}
```

Example, uniq by group . . .

```
    -bash-4.2$ uniq --group=both -f 1 original_file 

1447790360      99999   99999   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50

1447790362      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790365      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790368      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790371      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790374      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790377      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790380      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790383      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790386      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50

1447790388      20.25   20.25   99999   99999   99999   99999

1447790389      99999   99999   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50

1447790391      20.00   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50

1447790394      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790397      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790400      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
```

Then grep for line before and after every empty line and strip blank lines:

```
-bash-4.2$ uniq --group=both -f 1 original_file |grep -B1 -A1 ^$ |grep -Ev "^$|^--$"
1447790360      99999   99999   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790362      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790386      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790388      20.25   20.25   99999   99999   99999   99999
1447790389      99999   99999   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790391      20.00   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790394      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790400      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
```

Tah dahhh! 
Pretty good.

Comment: Very late with this answer I know :-7. I was surprised uniq was not mentioned in the answers here. I like the awk and sed and perl answers but uniq is probably the right tool for the job here.

Answer (score 3):

With `awk` one liner:

```
awk '{n=$2$3$4$5$6$7}l1!=n{if(p)print l0; print; p=0}l1==n{p=1}{l0=$0; l1=n}END{print}' file
```

The whole point is to manipulate few variables: `n` stores all fields except first in current line, `l1` the same for previous line and `l0` the whole previous line. The `p` is just a flag to mark if previous line was already printed.

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -ne '($t, $r) = /([0-9]+\s+)(.*)/;
          print "$pt$p\n$_" if $r ne $p;
          $p = $r;
          $pt = $t;
          }{
          print $t, $r' input-file \
| sort -nu | tail -n+2
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line.
- `$t` is the timestamp plus whitespace, `$r` is the "rest".
- `$p` is the previous rest, `$pt` is the previous timestamp.
- the last line is always printed

Perl prints some of the lines twice, `sort -nu` should remove the duplicates. `tail` removes the first empty line.

Answer (score 0):

A awk version:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN                      { rep=0  ; prev="" ; OFS=FS="     "}
!rep && prev== $2          { rep=1  ; prev=$2 ;          next }
rep  && prev== $2          { time=$1 ;                   next }
rep  && prev!= $2          { rep=0  ; print time, prev;       }
                           { print  ; prev=$2                 }
END                        { if(rep){ print time, prev}       }
```

- `rep` = inside a repetition?
- `prev` = previous number values
- `time` = previous time-stamp

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e:t -e'$!{1N;N;s/\( .*\)\(\n[^ ]*\1\)\{2\}$/\1\2/;tt' -e'P;D;}' <in >out
```

...that works. it recursively substitutes away the second in a series of three of input lines which it deems to be identical from the second space-delimited field on. it will continue to draw another input line to replace each it substitutes away until it can no longer do so. only when it cannot match three such similar lines will it `P`rint the first in its buffer before `D`eleting it and cycling back to try again with the two that remain and the next line of input.

with GNU or BSD `sed`:

```
sed -Ee:t -e'1N;$!N;s/( .*)(\n[^ ]*\1){2}$/\1\2/;tt' -eP\;D <in >out
```

---

```
1447790360      99999   99999   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790362      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790386      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790388      20.25   20.25   99999   99999   99999   99999
1447790389      99999   99999   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790391      20.00   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790394      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
1447790400      20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.25   20.50
```